# Using recursion to find a sequence of sums and products that equals a given number

Tags: ruby, recursion, methods

I'm trying to translate this example of recursion from Eloquent Javascript into Ruby.

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
// → (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

So far I've only got the following, which I understand is completely wrong. I'm trying to challenge myself by learning to rewrite a concept I don't fully understand yet.

```
def find_solution(n)
  i = 1 
  history = ""
  if (i *= 3) > n && (i += 5) > n 
    return nil 
  elsif i == n 
    return history 
  else 
    return (i *= 3 && history << "#{i} * 3") || (i += 5 && history << "#{i} + 5")
  end 
  find_solution
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The difference from js code is that you can’t define a method inside a method in ruby, so you have to define `find` outside of `find_solution` or use lambda functions.

Here’s the example with separate method:

```
def find(target, start, history)
  if start == target
    history
  elsif start < target
    find(target, start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
      find(target, start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  end
end

def find_solution(target)
  find(target, 1, "1")
end

puts find_solution(24)
```

Here’s the example with lambda:

```
def find_solution(target)
  find = ->(start, history) {
    if start == target
      history
    elsif start < target
      find.(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
        find.(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
    end
  }

  find.(1, "1")
end

puts find_solution(24)
```

Note that calling lambda functions is different from calling general method (`find.(a, b, c)` instead of `find(a,b,c)`)

Comment: Nice. For the first example, there's no need to define a second method just for default parameters. You could use `find(target, start=1, history="1")`

Comment: Using a helper method definitely made me understand it better. Thanks! I will look into lambda functions and how to use them. Is there any reason to use lambda over proc in this problem?

Comment: You're welcome. No, the difference between lambdas and procs doesn't affect on the solution.

Comment: Dan, for Eric to be notified of your comment addressed to him you need to include "@EricDuminil" in the comment. (Even though I have not included  at-danraybernard In this comment, you will be notified that I posted it because it's your question.)

Comment: You *can* nest a method definition inside a method definition in Ruby, it just means a completely different thing than it does in ECMAScript (or Scheme or Scala or any language with nested subroutines). In ECMAScript, it creates a function that is nested within the outer function. In Ruby, it creates a method that when you call it defines another method.